# ng-content: transclude the content of the container element, and not the element itself?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a modal dialog component based on Bootstrap with three primary child elements: *title, summary* and *footer*:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  template: `<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><ng-content select="header"></ng-content></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-content select="summary"></ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <ng-content select="footer"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
})
export class ModalComponent {
}
```

The intention is to simplify the Bootstrap boilerplate:

```
<modal>
  <header>Hello world!</header>
  <summary>A  message</summary>
  <footer>Dialog footer</footer>
</modal>
```

Unfortunately, the containing element (*header*, *summary* and *footer*) are also included in the "transclusion," which violates the Bootstrap format. Can I only transclude the container nodes' content?

Comment: I like this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about wrapping the markup to transclude in `<ng-container>` elements and using another type of selector to fetch it from `<ng-content>` (attribute selector, CSS class selector...)?

`<ng-container>` is supposed to have less interference with existing layout/CSS.

From the consumer's viewpoint:

```html
<modal>
  <ng-container header>Hello world!</ng-container>
  <ng-container class="summary">A  message</ng-container>
</modal>
```

Inside the modal component's template:

```html
<!-- Attribute selector -->
<ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>

<!-- CSS class selector -->
<ng-content select=".summary"></ng-content>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as ng-container is a virtual element - you get the following exception:
DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method

Comment: I'm also a bit puzzled by this answer being the accepted one with 4 up vote as it doesn't seem to work.